# There are $n$ teams each competing with another one time. Score of win is $+1$ , of loss is $-1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There  are $n$ teams each competing with another one time. Score of win is $+1$, of loss is $-1$

a) Prove that we can write teams in a list so that each one has won against the team under itself in the list.

c) For a specific team named A, in how many ways it can have the total score of $k$ at the end **while not having negative total score during games**? $1-n \leq k \leq n-1$

Comment: What have you tried? Can you find a solution for small values of $n$? For (a) there's no answer if every match was a tie.

Comment: yeah I made a typo .now its edited @EthanBolker